# spam prevention mechanism - earn 10 reputation to post more hyperlinks no more

Tags: feature-request, reputation, spam-detection

My prior rant (see on edits) proved somewhat valuable - there is now a not-anymore-so-*new* feature that gives us 100 points (leaving us at the funny 101 state) when creating a new user on sites from SE network, proven you had enough points (200) in at least one.

Now I still think 10 rep points is too much of a requirement to new users to post more than 1 hyperlink. And [I'm not alone (at least among skeptics)](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367/remove-number-of-links-restriction-for-new-users). If the intention is preventing spam, why not *simply applying the **SPAM prevention mechanism*** (that one with the cute robot image) to everyone with less than 10 points and remove this limit once and for all?

Comment: @Cawas Stack Overflow does not use any Uservoice sites.

Comment: @waiwai: it used to, a long time ago, in a galaxy far far away...

Comment: @voyager Yes I'm aware of that, but considering this topic was made today, and the user has only registered on the trilogy today... I'm pretty sure that uservoice is not applicable to this particular question.

Comment: well, what does it use? it's a kind of bulletin system I see in other places, but none have links to how they do it!

Comment: The "SPAM prevention mechanism" is called a [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA). See especially [Circumvention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA#Circumvention)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

<sup>I've just stumbled upon this old question of mine, and ...</sup>

I decided to do a little test creating a new user to see if it was still valid. Well...

Since then, a lot has changed in the StackExchange Network (which wasn't even called that back then). Now new users have a lot of stuff to do before posting a question. And preventing spam is certainly not dealt like it was before - I couldn't even see any mechanism, which means it's probably much more advanced now. :-)

Thanks to Mat's comment, what I could see is that there is [still a limitation to posting hyperlinks, among other restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user). I could post a test question with 3 links, 1 of them were "internal" within SEN. I think that's fair enough.

<sup>So, even if no engineer responsible to do those modifications ever got to read this question, I find it awesome they still addressed it! :-)</sup>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user - either you somehow didn't test correctly, or there's a bug, that limitation is still supposed to apply.

Comment: @Mat I didn't mention 1 of those links were internal (to stackoverflow, not even to meta) but I did test it. Thanks for the link, I'll update the answer!

Answer (score 9):

You don't have much reputation on the sites, as you've been a member of all the sites for just a day.

You seem to be more interested in superuser, and you already have 41 rep points there. You'll realize that the more you participate on the sites, the more rep you'll get at a fast enough rate (no more than 200 points from votes casted on your posts in a single day).

Reputation is not shared across the sites because the rep is supposed to be a measure of your participation in one of the sites, and in a smaller sense, knowledge about the site's domain. Every site has a specific knowledge domain, your knowledge about programming does not mean you have a good knowledge of networking.

Comment: Fair enough. I still highly dislike this system... First, as mentioned on the title, because of THAT. Second then comes every other limiting on the site itself. Maybe it shouldn't be equally shared, but at least BASIC things like recognizing someone as not spammer and allowing to have basic features such as "multiple links" would be enough.

Comment: @Cawas it IS provided. You can associate your accounts after getting 200 reputation, and you are able to use all of the features of the site.

Comment: Huh? 200 doesn't seem basic at all.

Comment: It depends how you accumulate reputation: by asking *lots* of question or answering a few. 200 doesn't seem much, once you get over the initial learning curve.

Comment: "once you get over the initial" beats the purpose of what I've said.

Comment: @Cawas: if you "still highly dislike this system", no one is asking you to stay.

Comment: but I want to see how down(voted) can this question go! :P

Answer (score 2):

Have you [associated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/account-association-between-websites) your accounts?

There is a bonus involved, if, as random says, you have 200 reputation on one of the accounts.

Apart from the bonus, it would be misleading to share reputation between accounts.

For example, answering questions on SO with reputation earned on SU might persuade readers that there was some kind of expertise involved.

Comment: Needs 200 rep on one account for the bonus.

Comment: I did associate. If it would be misleading, thing I haven't thought at first, then just share enough rep, or whatever other kind of measure, so I can be considered not-spammer from just one. I mean, c'mon, this is highly frustrating!

Comment: You may have noticed that 'questions' on Meta are voted up or down according to whether people agree with what you say. On the SO/SU/SF sites it more or less depends on technical merit. Most of your contributions to Meta have been downvoted. Would you *really* want to lose reputation on the other sites because you've said some unpopular things?

Comment: Sure, why not? I got the idea on separating some things, but other things would fit better linked together. I'm great for spotting those system issues, not being able to explain myself and seeing it evolve to fixing it later on. Eventually I'll learn how to better use this ability, or just drop it.