# First Impressions: Great interface, interesting concept, bad implementation

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, new-users, spam

Stack Overflow does make it easy for new users, but not so much. I'm new here and, as such, I spent some time reading before doing anything. And then I go out to try it.

After spending some time on Super User, I went to Meta, as recommended, to ask a question about the interface (I didn't know about doctype yet). I've elaborated on the whole question, putting links and all, only to get marked as a "spammer" by an unjustified prevention mechanism.

I say unjustified because I had already proven, by its own concept, on the other associated site, that I'm not a spammer by earning the freaking reputation (bad naming, by the way - everyone wants to have "reputation" in real life, but this should not be the case here. I believe).

So, big frustration, after already having a bad first impression. It's the reason I did all this in the first place.

Maybe it's just me, and I'm sorry for bringing all this text here. Not that anyone will read this. But maybe this system could be improved for new users.

That's all. Or so it was until I got a new deception:

> New users can only post questions every 20 minutes; try again later.

C'mon people! There must be better ways to fight bots and spammers! This interface is so innovative and yet this kind of thing seem so stupid!

This is how I currently feel about this whole Stack Overflow system.

Comment: Well, you already "got around" that 20 minute per posting thing. http://superuser.com/questions/109885/instant-email-alerts-and-notifications

Comment: @Cawas, would you like to suggest innovative and effective means of fighting bots and spammers?

Comment: well, thanks for the writeup on the first impressions.  if you stick around, give us another critique in 6 months so we can see how much of this is valid critique and how much of this is new-user-not-used-to-how-site-works.

Comment: It must be very encouraging to have 5 questions and still be stuck at 1 rep...

Comment: Simple rule. If you come to a place which is working and quite successful for more than a year, slamming the door and shouting complaints before even really knowing, it is not likely to get your message heard. Stay around for a while, show that you care by actually following how these sites work. Then you can complain, as long as it is structured and constructed. I mean, look at me, I spend most of my time complaining (more about people than about sites, ok), and I still get reputation from it. ;-)

Comment: To put your *After spending some time on Super User* into perspective a bit: you're a member for 26 hours and already posted 5 questions on that site alone? (And another 4 on Meta within 15 hours.) That's a *very first impression* indeed.

Comment: Look, I think it's pretty clear I've enjoyed it at first, and then had some disarrangements with the interface. I just hope whoever is making it can at least think about how this has been to me. If they are, like I would, trying to make this as easy as possible for first users, I think this is good input from someone not so dummy still doing stupid things not only because I'm also not that smart, but because there are things on the site that can get better.

Comment: @Cawas - Then work on the way you express the "things on the site that can get better". If you check this meta site, you will notice that it's mostly this. Daily propositions of improvements, by hundreds of people. And it works, and many propositions are taken into account by the people making the site. Like I said, be nice, follow the rules, and things should be fine.

Comment: @Gnoupi I see, so I should first earn their trust, then slam the door, shout and offer som tea! Note taken (not seriously tho). :)

Comment: curious to know the updated impressions of collaborators from back then. myself, i think i changed a lot. probably, in part, thanks to you all. my own impression spending many minutes reading thorough all of this, which i obviously completely forgot about by now: i still don't see exactly why or how i triggered so many people... but i certainly learned to be more explicitly caring with written words. ps: got back here due to a site notification (in this case, a downvote), which sometimes drag my attention (i actually check them all out, when not too redundant, but that's a whole other topic).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On a personal level, I appreciate that you did spent time reading before participating actively. However that conflicted the fact that you have problem asking questions in a well... 'nicer' manner.

Before I continue, please understand that I'm neutral and am trying to help more than anything. Here's my comments on some of your questions on Meta (in chrono order):

- **[spam prevention mechanism - earn 10 reputation to post more hyperlinks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39666/)**
  and you started the question body with "I find this a little bit stupid...". You used an error message as the title and then attacked it directly in the body. Not a very good move for a first question. You might want to be constructive but I find it more tempting to rebutt your question than to support it, even if it's worth supporting.
- **[What interface software system is used in superuser?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39669/)**
  I think you were getting the hang of it and you've got your answer for this one.
- **[asking question notify checkbox bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39671/)**
  Honestly, took a couple of re-reads for me to understand your question and I'm not the only one.
- **[First Impressions: Great interface, interesting concept, bad implementation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39674/)**
  This is the one that prompted me to read your other posts and also give my 2 cents.
- **[Instant email alerts and notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39676/)**
  Rather well-structured question with supporting links and numbered list, though I can sense some 'heat' in your tone. Eventually you ended with this sentence, "*Simple as that. I don't mind receiving too much notifications. I only mind receiving NONE!*". Not pretty I must say, it sounded like an angry paying client during an UAT feedback session.

I think I just used 30 minutes of my time to compile this reply. Anyway in short, the guys here can be 'nasty' at times, if you were to step on their toes or put up screenshots with soulless circles :P. The thing is, however nice they (we) maybe, most of them (or us) do not really tolerate blantant attacks albeit trying to be constructive, which I believe you are. It's the manner of delivery which perhaps should be improved.

Comment: +1. I'm sure the criticism is basically well-intentioned, but take it easy and take some time first.

Comment: I have always assumed I do have a lot to improve on my "amazing" communication skills. You could see that right on my description - I am confused. Sorry for all the trouble, and thanks for so much patience.

Answer (score 8):

If you really want to help improving the site, take the **time** and build trust from community first, and go step by step with constructive manners.

Just saying "THIS IS BAD!, THIS IS BAD!" will be just ends in unexpected results.

And also there is policy and rules on every sites, learn by reading FAQ, old questions and find the concepts why they are doing like that too.

Comment: Actually, just saying "THIS IS BAD!, THIS IS BAD!" will yield quite *expected* results me thinks ;-)

Comment: @fretje, The *expected* results you mean is downvotes, right? :D

Comment: Well, I got really frustrated by supposedly minor things on the system. I don't really care that much for the downvotes but doesn't this show the community also don't care that much about new users? People like to bash other people on their own frustration. I like better bashing on the systems.

Comment: @Cawas, there are literaly thousands of new users week in week out, but we don't often see responses like yours. I'm not saying the all the rest are happy and/or quiet. The fact that we responded to your posts do mean that the community cares. Just don't expect a smile if you don't give it first.

Comment: Here I'd like to just put a smiley :-)

Comment: @Cawas, If I remember correctly, one of your answer had some not-so-good words like *S..t* or something, I guess, its got flagged and got deleted, those kind of things could cause some impression down. Please understand that Community need to make the site clean and nice.

Comment: @S.Mark: It was an answer to my own question and just an exclamation expression. I was hoping it was not going to be a big issue. Anyways, one try out only, and there it will stay.

Comment: @o.k.w Was your web link on your profile supposed to work? http://74er.net/

Comment: @Cawas, yes but don't bother, nothing there :P

Comment: @o.k.w too bad - I love links. :D

Comment: @o.k.w. still nothing there! 