# Instant email alerts and notifications

Tags: feature-request, notifications, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Instant email alerts and notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24659/instant-email-alerts-and-notifications)

If I click on [my name on the top of the screen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/143411/cawas) and then click on [user feed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/143411), at the bottom of that page, I'll get an RSS for updates. Great for notifications of messages I should read, as they're related to questions I've subscribed somehow.

Why can't we have an option to just receive those notifications through e-mail instantly? Not using feedburner or any other external source.

I understand this is [not the first time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24659/instant-email-alerts-and-notifications) this question is asked, and [there are nice deviants](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have) from this.

But it's still *not answered*! Hopefully it's for having the wrong approach.

I just need to get email notifications, at very least, from direct answers to my questions. No need to try and automate anything.

> #### Ways to get instant notification:
>
> 1. opt-in config to auto-notify when getting answer to your question
> 2. opt-in config to auto-notify when getting comments on your answer / question
> 3. individually choose to get warnings on either the selected answer or question from anyone else with an opt-in config to auto-notify on the ones you've answered / commented.

Simple as that. I don't mind receiving too much notifications. I only mind receiving NONE!

Comment: This is your first day here. And you have posted five "questions" whining about the site. Please take some time to think and organize your ideas at least before posting.

Comment: @Cawas: You can bump an 'old' question by adding an answer to it in stead of posting a new question.

Comment: @fretje - note that this is valid only for Meta, such behaviour

Comment: @fretje and @Gnoupi: Thanks. I thought since it was answered it wouldn't get any attention. Should I re-post this question as an answer in there? Can anyone do that for me, since I can't post that many links?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has actually been answered in one of the most recent SO [Podcast #83](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/02/podcast-83/).

From the notes for the episode:

> I am not a fan of email, to put it mildly, as I wrote in Is Email = Efail and Email: The Variable Reinforcement Machine. Given my discomfort with email, I struggle with the role of email on Stack Overflow — mostly trying to keep it at arms’ length while using it appropriately.

The short version is it is never going to happen this way. He explains his reasons well in the Podcast, and to be honest I agree personally. I despise e-mail in general and try and keep it to a minimum. I am currently on various mailing lists and the amount of information a get from them makes it absolutely useless. I prefer my RSS reader over e-mail.

If you post a question and expect immediate results your expecting to much. Granted the Trilogy has built a reputation for providing fast answers, it is not guaranteed that it will happen. I have had a few questions that never gained any response due to them being extremely specialised or unique.

Comment: Great info. Didn't know there was even a podcast about SO. May I ask why you are so against e-mail? Just point me some links, if you will. I can already imagine if you have so many mailing lists - I have always hated them.

RSS readers, as far as I know, are not nearly as effective with filtering as are e-mail clients. And surely not as widespread if you want to actually read / receive some data. So, while I can understand tastes, I can't understand why ruling this option out.

Comment: The answer to your question is long and completed. The short version, similiar reasons then Jeff. With RSS I have more options and control, and most RSS feeders, for example, Google Reader, offer much more advanced filtering options then can be applied with e-mail. Email has a place, but not in this context.

Comment: I was really hoping for some links showing why RSS is so much better than e-mail. Maybe I'm missing gReader's features - I've never seem a single filtering option there, out of the few it offers, that I can't do on any mail client, specially gmail. I'll investigate more on this. And thanks once again for the attention.